# MVC Core 2 - && operator in lambda expression not working

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Visual studio - MVC Core2 using Microsoft ASP.NET Controller

I am trying to filter records based on a user and if its marked for deletion (bool data type)

I am using the && operator and trying to order by dates column, however its not working

Here is my code

```
var DataContext = _context.Shops_Basket.Include(c => c.products)
                .Where(c => c.Username == user && c.IsDeleted == 0)).Orderby dates desc;
```

Comment: If it is a boolean, try `!c.IsDeleted` instead of `c.IsDeleted == 0` ?

Comment: What language and/or framework is this? Please edit your tags to specify.

Comment: @AurelBílý in both cases it doesnt work, gives error  
Error CS0815 Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your OrderBy is wrong in the above. Also the error you are getting sounds like a type-name collision to me. Try to start your variables with lower case letter to avoid this:

```
var dataContext = _context.Shops_Basket
                          .Include(c => c.products)
                          .Where(c => c.Username == user
                                   && !c.IsDeleted)
                          .OrderByDescending(c => c.dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Orderby dates desc` is not valid c#. Probably you are confused by SQL. You need to use `OrderByDescending`:

```
var dataContext = _context.Shops_Basket.Include(c => c.products)
    .Where(c => c.Username == user && c.IsDeleted == 0)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.dates);
```

Also note, we have [naming conventions in C#](https://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards). Local variables are starting with a lower character. Underscores like `Shops_Basket` we usualy do not use. Instead the better `DbSet` name would be `ShopsBasket`.

Comment: I suspect the underscore is because the datamodel was generated from a database, and the table has underscore, which is not at all uncommon on the SQL side.

Comment: Ah okay, you are on the Database First track :) Didn't know, just wanted to point it out. @DrunkenCodeMonkey